# Use function but run it again if it has the same result as function before

Tags: php

So i've made this function where you random a colour. Problem is Im gonna print the same function 8 times and I dont want two of the prints to return same variable. So basically i want it to run the function again if it has printed the colour before.

```
function random_color(){
$color_numb = "8";

$color = rand(1, $color_numb);

if($color == "1"){
  $type = "Blue";
}
if($color == "2"){
  $type = "Red";
}
if($color == "3"){
  $type = "Orange";
}
if($color == "4"){
  $type = "Green";
}
if($color == "5"){
  $type = "Yellow";
}
if($color == "6"){
  $type = "Black";
}
if($color == "7"){
  $type = "Purple";
}
if($color == "8"){
  $type = "White";
}
return $type;

}
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
print random_color();
```

So any idea how i can manage to do this?

Comment: Either take the numbers 1 through 8 and randomize them and then print out the list in that order OR remove the items from the list when you've printed them.

Comment: Instead of keeping running the function until you find something that isn't hit yet you should remove items from the pool. Or you funtion will get slower and slower.

Comment: BTW, that string of `if` statements is silly. Use an array of color names, and then `$type = $names[$color]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `random_color()` function and your 8 `print`s, try this :

```
$colors = array();
$colors[] = "Blue";
$colors[] = "Red";
$colors[] = "Orange";
$colors[]= "Green";
$colors[]= "Yellow";
$colors[] = "Black";
$colors[]= "Purple";
$colors[]= "White";
shuffle($colors);
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
   echo $colors[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need 8 different colors in different order, just create array, fill it with colors and then ranomize (shuffle) array with this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

```
$colors = array();
$colors[] = 'red';
$colors[] = 'green';
....
shuffle($colors);
```

Comment: Im gonna try this. I'll come with result in a minute

Comment: Okey, im not following what im gonna return.

Comment: You are returning anything. Your result is at $colors, so just read it $colors[0], $colors[1] etc

Comment: Alright i tried that, and im now getting this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: Still getting the same error. Do you want me to paste the code?

Comment: @user2705154 you just shuffle the array randomly, then foreach it.  The order of the colors will be random because of the shuffle.

Comment: @user2705154 I dont see any problem with code.. what error do you have ?

Comment: When i print the function.  Array to string conversion in

Comment: <?php echo random_color(); ?>

Comment: @user2705154 You cant use echo for array, use print_r(random_color()) instead

Comment: Alright, no more errors. Now when i print the array it prints the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also based on session:

```
<?php
//put this line at top of the page before printing anything
session_start();

function random_color(){
  $color_numb = "8";

  $random = rand(1, $color_numb);
  $colors  = array(1 => "Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Purple", "White");

  $current_color = $colors[$random];

  if(!isset($_SESSION['oldcolor'])){
    $_SESSION['oldcolor'] = $current_color;
    return $current_color;
  }
  while($current_color == $_SESSION['oldcolor']){
   $current_color = $colors[rand(1, $color_numb)];
  }
  $_SESSION['oldcolor'] = $current_color;

  return $current_color;
}

echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
echo random_color();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display the colors on demand, but never show a duplicate color, then you can do this:

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/buH4M/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Show Next Color" />
<input id="listall" type="button" value="List All Found Values" />
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
var aCN = ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple', 'white'];
var aFound = new Array();

$('#mybutt').click(function () {
    xx = 1;
    while (xx == 1) {
        getcol = random_color();
        if (aFound.indexOf(getcol) == -1) {
            alert(getcol);
            aFound.push(getcol);
            xx = 0;
        } else {
            if (aFound.length > 7) {
                alert('You already saw all values');
                xx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
});

$('#listall').click(function () {
    if (aFound.length == 0) {
        alert('Nothing seen yet...');
        return false;
    }
    Object.keys(aFound).forEach(function (key) {
        alert(aFound[key]);
    });
});

function random_color() {
    $color_numb = "8";
    $color = Math.floor(Math.random() * $color_numb);

    myCol = aCN[$color];
    return myCol + ' - ' + $color;
}
```